# Play sound with Android's media player Processing

Tags: java, android, processing, android-sound

So I found this code online but for some reason, it doesn't work. I mean it didn't crash but it just couldn't play the file
code:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

MediaPlayer mp;
Context context; 
Activity act;
AssetFileDescriptor afd;

void setup() {
  act = this.getActivity();
  context = act.getApplicationContext();
  try {
    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    afd = context.getAssets().openFd("calm1.mp3");//which is in the data folder
    mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor());
    mp.prepare();
  } 
  catch(IOException e) {
    println("file did not load"+e);
  }
  mp.start();
};

void draw() {
};
```

and the output is:

```
file did not load java.io.FileNotFoundException: calm1.mp3
```

pssst im using processing

Comment: Data folder mean?

Comment: Its in the data folder and its exact name is calm1.mp3

Comment: sketch/data/calm1

Comment: you likely placed the file in wrong place. It has to be in assets

Comment: Im using processing in the Android processing development environment (APDE) and files that  your sketch uses are in the data folder

Comment: then you need to use the code which will load them from data folder, not from assets folder

Comment: everything in apde by default is in the data folder

Answer (score 0):

This question is a bit old but it needs an answer (as it appears on the search engines).

The following code works the way you asked for. Is a little bit different than yours, it sets the DataSource directly from the AssetFileDescriptor object:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.content.res.AssetFileDescriptor;
import android.content.Context;
import android.app.Activity;

void setup() {
    AssetFileDescriptor descriptor = this.getActivity().getAssets().openFd("calm1.mp3");

    mp = new MediaPlayer();
    mp.setDataSource(descriptor.getFileDescriptor(), descriptor.getStartOffset(), descriptor.getLength());
    descriptor.close();
    mp.prepare();
    mp.setVolume(1f, 1f);
    mp.setLooping(true);
    mp.start();
}
```